# Character count for newline in asp.net mvc textarea vs jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC web application. I have a textarea in the view and it's binded to a model which has maximum length of 1000.

```
//Html:
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, 12, 50, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Mandatory" })

//Model class:
[Required]
[DisplayName("Event Description")]
[MaxLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Maximum {1} characters.")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

I'm also using jQuery to display a message for the user so that they know how many characters are left to enter:

```
    $('#Description').keyup(function () {
        var maxlen = 1000;
        var count = $(this).val().length;
        var charLeft = maxlen - count;
        var string = charLeft + " chracters left"
        if (count > maxlen) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxlen);
        }
        else {
            $("#descriptionCharCount").text(string);
        }
    });
```

I found that when there's a new line entered, ASP.NET will insert 2 spaces and therefore increase the character count by 2. But jQuery only increase by 1. This resulting a mismatch. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why it happens: Windows uses two characters (`\r\n`), to represent a new line, whereas some browsers only use one of these characters (`\n`). So when the model binder converts the input into a string, you actually have a string that uses two characters.

There are a number of ways to try to address this, with varying levels of "correctness." Here are some posts that address the issue:

- http://blog.sarathonline.com/2009/09/javascript-maxlength-for-textarea-with.html
- http://kenegozi.com/blog/2010/04/19/newlines-in-textarea-are-treated-differently-on-different-browsers/
- [jQuery validate textarea maxlength bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346790/jquery-validate-textarea-maxlength-bug)

It seems to me that the most correct way is to take a two-pronged approach:

1. Write your length-checking algorithm in a way that ignores the `\r` characters, and
2. Use [a model binder that removes `\r` characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704415/120955) from strings sent to the server, prior to server-side validation.

However, bear in mind that this might have a few unexpected results. For example, if users download a file based on the input they've saved, and then open it in a program like Notepad (which only recognizes `\r\n` combos as newlines) they wouldn't see the line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll "kind of" use the 1st approach. But I will do the opposite, which is replacing '\n' with '\r\n' in jQuery length calculation.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering that at first, but figured it might confuse people to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and see their character count jump by 2.